# how to enable path info iis 6 & 7

Tags: iis, pathinfo

I am trying to use path info in my asp.net web application. I am using iis 6 on the production machine and iis 7.5 on my home computer.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `Request.PathInfo` ? If yes, this doesn't need to be enabled, it's a property of each request.

Comment: iis is redirecting me to the default page and no to the correct one. I think that IIS doesn't recognize what page I am trying to redirect to, so it's redirecting to the default.

Comment: Then I guess you should clarify your question: what did you do and how, what happens when you execute it, and what would you like it to do really? Then we could help you with either configuring IIS, or with redirection, etc.